# I need to add WooCommerce provided code in my custom html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I recently purchase Woo Commerce Follow up Email extension and I want to add "Sign-ups, Subscriber Lists, and Email Newsletters" they provide the code

```
[fue_subscribe label="Email:" placeholder="Your email address" submit_text="Subscribe" success_message="You have been subscribed!"]
```

The above code working fine on widgets and post/pages but when I add the code in my custom it not works

Can anyone please tell me how to add this type of Wordpress code in custom HTML or PHP

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this inside your theme file:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[fue_subscribe label="Email:" placeholder="Your email address" submit_text="Subscribe" success_message="You have been subscribed!"]');
```